# HTML5: Video and canvas drawImage() function on Android and Crosswalk

Tags: html, cordova, canvas, html5-canvas, crosswalk-runtime

I'm trying to draw a video frame on canvas. It works well on desktops, but there are issues on Chrome on Android devices.

Please see the example:
http://buildar.com/static/drawimage/minimal.html

I've tested it on various Android devices and the only that's working on is Android 5 with Crosswalk (Cordova app).
After removing the Crosswalk or trying on other Android version, the drawImage function doesn't work.

I've found several related Chromium bug reports, but according to them, the issue seems to be fixed
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=501208

What can be the reason for it to work only on Android 5 + Crosswalk - if Crosswalk fully replaces the device Webview, wouldn't it work on older Android versions as well?

Is there any other way of capturing the video frame? I'm currently researching converting the video to `<img>`, alternative video plugin, using Webgl, taking video screenshot, but haven't discovered anything so far that could possibly work.

Comment: I think I remember some video formats would taint the canvas on mobile (some DRM in mp4 formats). I don't think there would be any fix for this... Only workaround for some UA would be to try with webm instead of mp4

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I actually did try using webm and ogg instead, but it didn't work (you can also see the demo in the link I've added above)

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem on Android 4.4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985960/the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data-error-on-android-no-error-on

Comment: Sorry, still no luck. Though, I believe that your problem might be related to something else - I noticed that the issue I've reported affects devices pre 4.2.2 and there is no error message.